# How to revert back to older xorg?

Tags: xorg, updates, synaptic

Since the last update of ubuntu 12.04, the system won't boot into gui anymore. It states that it was unable to load the graphics drivers and gives me 4 options, these are:

- run in low graphics mode for 1 session
- reconfigure graphics
- troubleshoot the error
- exit to console login

whichever option I choose, it doesn't solve anything. For instance, when i choose to reconfigure graphics and then switch to vesa drivers, the screen goes back to the option list.

So i configured xorg.conf to vesa myself, and i see in the update history that ubuntu updated xserver-xorg-core and xserver-common whereas i blocked these updates in synaptic since i'm aware that updating these files caused troubles with my particular video card (radeon hd6800). So my solution is probably to revert these files to the older (working) versions. How can I do this please (in particular xserver-xorg-core since i think this is the main cause of my problem).

thanks!

output of `ls /etc/X11`

```
-app-defaults
xorg.conf
Xreset
-cursors
xorg.conf-backup-120529144709
Xreset.d
-default-display-manager
xorg.conf.fglrx-0
-Xresources
-fonts
xorg.conf.fglrx-1
Xsession
-rgb.txt
xorg.conf.fglrx-2
Xsession.d -X
xorg.conf.original-0
-Xsession.options
-xinit
xorg.conf.original-1
-Xwrapper.config
-xkb
xorg.conf.vesa
```

Output of `sudo aptitude show xserver-xorg-core | grep Versie` (read: Version in Flemish)

```
Versie: 2:1.11.4-0ubuntu10.2
```

Comment: Can you include the output of **sudo aptitude show  xserver-xorg-core | grep Version**

Comment: The output of `ls /etc/X11` would be useful too.  Ubuntu should automatically back up your Xorg.conf file on a distribution upgrade, back reverting the config file alone won't necessarily help you if the problem isn't in the config.

Comment: @adempewolff
The output of ls /etc/X11 is
-app-defaults             xorg.conf                      Xreset
-cursors                  xorg.conf-backup-120529144709  Xreset.d
-default-display-manager  xorg.conf.fglrx-0              -Xresources
-fonts                    xorg.conf.fglrx-1              Xsession
-rgb.txt                  xorg.conf.fglrx-2              Xsession.d
-X                        xorg.conf.original-0               -Xsession.options
-xinit                    xorg.conf.original-1               -Xwrapper.config
-xkb                      xorg.conf.vesa(sry, couldn't find to code)

Comment: @mitch:
I have to leave grep version or it did not give me an output:

Versie: 2:1.11.4-0ubuntu10.2
Prioriteit: optioneel
Sectie: x11
Beheerder: Ubuntu X-SWAT <ubuntu-x@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architectuur: amd64
Ongecomprimeerde grootte: 4262 k
Hangt af van: xserver-common (>= 2:1.11.4-0ubuntu10.2), keyboard-configuration,
              udev (>= 149), libc6 (>= 2.15), libdrm2 (>= 2.3.1), libgcrypt11
              (>= 1.4.5), libpciaccess0 (>= 0.10.7), libpixman-1-0 (>= 0.21.6),
              libudev0 (>= 147), libxau6, libxdmcp6, libxfont1 (>= 1:1.4.2)
Beveelt aan: libgl1-mesa-dri (>= 7.10.2-4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem on my own by uninstalling the drivers and re-installing the ati proprietary drivers by following this guide: 
[What is the correct way to install proprietary ATI Catalyst Video Drivers (fglrx) directly from AMD?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-ati-catalyst-video-drivers-in-12-04-lts)

Answer (score 0):

Do you get to the login screen at least? does it crash after loading the desktop environment (i.e compiz) or before the login screen

if you can get the login screen, have you tried a Ubuntu-2d environment?

Comment: I only get the loginscreen when changing the xorg.conf to "vesa" drivers. Still, i do not get this when loading kernel 3.2.0.24, only with 3.0.0.19. 
Whith the other version or with vesa drivers turned off, i get the ubuntu loading screen and then it switches to console automatically.